# How do you do Rails' polymorphism/STI in Django?

Tags: django, single-table-inheritance, sti

I came across Proxy models in Django but they don't create the single-table polymorphic columns (polymorphable_id, polymorphable_type).  Is there any way to create sti/polymorphism in Django?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My team has used `django-polymorphic` for this before:

https://github.com/django-polymorphic/django-polymorphic

It is well maintained and has a lot of nice features. Good luck!

Comment: The parent is asking about single-table inheritance ("STI"), which `django-polymorphic` doesn't support. It works with concrete table inheritance instead. The main drawback is a lot of `INNER JOIN`s emitted when needing to construct child objects.